The dimensions of an $A$-algebra
Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity and $B$ be an $A$-algebra. So, we can consider $B$ as a commutative ring and then calculate its Krull dimension and also we can consider $B$ as an $A$-module and then calculate its dimension as an $A$-module $\dim B= \dim (A/ \operatorname{Ann}_A(B))$. My question is:
Are these dimensions the same number?
If yes, why?

Don't think so, Krull dimension is purely intrinsic to B and more a geometric invariant and hence does not necessarily care about $A$. For example $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ are high dimensional algebras over $\mathbb{Z}$ or even any extension, have themselves though Krull dimension 0.
